# Fail2ban accepted the customized jail but it did not detect the event

Tags: fail2ban

this problem drives me crazy.
I configured a jail to prevent excessive http post to my web server.

Seems the fail2ban server accepts my new jail but nothing takes effective in the fail2ban server.

Following are part of my jail.local configuration (sshd in fail2ban works perfectly btw).

```
#global setting
bantime  = 1h 
findtime  = 1h
maxretry = 5
backend = systemd
banaction = firewallcmd-rich-rules[actiontype=]
banaction_allports = firewallcmd-rich-rules[actiontype=]
[sshd]
# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
enabled  = true
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s

[webpost]
enabled  = true
filter   = webpost
logpath  = /var/log/message
```

Following is the webpost.conf in the filter.d/ folder:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*myserver python3.6\[.*\]: <HOST> - - \[.*\] ".*POST \/enquiry HTTP.*".*-$
ignoreregex =
datepattern = ^%%b  %%d %%H:%%M:%%S
```

The regex test in the fail2ban is working, the output is below:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/messages /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/webpost.conf
Running tests
=============
Use   failregex filter file : webpost, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : ^%b  %d %H:%M:%S : ^MON  Day 24hour:Minute:Second
Use         log file : /var/log/messages
Use         encoding : UTF-8
Results
=======
Failregex: 115 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [115] ^.*myserver python3.6\[.*\]: <HOST> - - \[.*\] ".*POST \/enquiry HTTP.*".*-$
`-
Ignoreregex: 0 total
Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [115989] ^MON  Day 24hour:Minute:Second
`-
Lines: 115989 lines, 0 ignored, 115 matched, 115874 missed
[processed in 2.65 sec]
```

The fail2ban log also shows everything loaded and worked fine.

```
2023-09-07 17:27:09,868 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [969]: NOTICE  [webpost] Jail started without 'journalmatch' set. Jail regexs will be checked against all journal entries, which is not advised for performance reasons.
2023-09-07 17:27:10,061 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [969]: INFO    [webpost] Jail is in operation now (process new journal entries)
2023-09-07 17:27:10,063 fail2ban.jail           [969]: INFO    Jail 'webpost' started
```

After I send lots of http post request to my website and looks like the fail2ban didn't detect any of the http post from the /var/log/message. The fail2ban only detects the sshd attempts. NO webpost detects at all!

```
2023-09-07 17:36:46,206 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:36:45
2023-09-07 17:36:48,739 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:36:48
2023-09-07 17:36:52,034 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:36:51
2023-09-07 17:36:55,241 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:36:54
2023-09-07 17:37:57,290 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:37:56
2023-09-07 17:37:57,769 fail2ban.actions        [969]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 180.101.88.228
2023-09-07 17:37:57,795 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [pam-generic] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:37:57
2023-09-07 17:37:59,280 fail2ban.filter         [969]: INFO    [sshd] Found 180.101.88.228 - 2023-09-07 17:37:58
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> `fail2ban.filtersystemd  [969]: NOTICE  [webpost] Jail started without 'journalmatch' set...`

Your default `backend` seems to be `systemd`, what means it'd monitor systemd journal not the logpath.

Simply add `backend = auto` to the jail:

```
  [webpost]
  ...
  logpath  = /var/log/message
+ backend = auto
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves my problem.

Comment: You're welcome... 
Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted"
(click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.)

Comment: I really don't get it while so few people here mark answers as accepted or upvote comments.

Comment: @mzzhmh hey lazy guy, make everybody a favor and accept this answer.